How Does God Love?
If God is omnipotent (Psalm 115:3), then God is immeasurably perfect in every way. I feel that "human" or "human-like" emotions would detract quite a bit from divine perfection, but does God also love all his creations? Romans 9:13 mentions God's hatred for evil, which he sees in Esau, whom he also hates. I understand that God did not directly create evil and sin and it was only a consequence of free will. Even so, the Bible said that God hated not only his actions but he hated Esau himself.
1 John 4:16 (ESV):

So we have come to know and to believe the love that God has for us. God is love, and whoever abides in love abides in God, and God abides in him.

God is love, but God is also the embodiment of everything, including hate and other antonyms of love. God is everything because God created everything, and everything he has created is an extension of him (Colossians 1:16).
Furthermore, we can not answer the question well without defining "perfect" first. I have always thought of perfection not as the absence of imperfection but as the acceptance and inclusion of everything that makes it. But that is not everyone's definition, especially not how the Scriptures define it (Deuteronomy 32:4). Assuming my opinion is true, there's a straightforward conclusion to God's perfection: God's perfection would include all of his "imperfections," making him perfect but also humane.  But in the Bible (2 Timothy 3:16), he is described as divine without human error. If God were a perfect divine being, how would he feel? Or have any emotions at all? If God is a divine being, I can't understand how he would feel, including his love.
(I apologize in advance if my question isn't framed very well, i'm not very used to translating my thoughts into coherent questions )

Welcome to C.SE! This is a very good question! But it might be too broad for this site, we'll see how other users feel about it. Do you have a particular denomination/school of thought within Christianity that you're interested in hearing from?

@DarkMalthorp I have actually tried to ask this question on other sites as well, but they have been closed and i’ve been directed to this site. If there is another site that would be a good fit I would love to know so I could get answers there. I am asking from a more secular perspective as somebody who doesn’t personally believe in the existence of God but adores the Bible and theology. I don’t think there’s a particular denomination I am more interested in than others, but if I were more specific I would say catholicism, in particular Roman catholicism.

They know the answer to this question who have experienced the love of God. "We love him, because he first loved us." 1 John 4:19 KJV.

@Nigel this should be an answer.

God loves by the simple fact of his being. The human emotion of love is but a hazy reflection of the perfect love that is God.

"I can't understand" - indeed, there are multiple scriptures about how we cannot fully comprehend God.

The basic answer is fairly simple. God is love means he has good intentions for and cares for his creatures and this love is proved by sending his only Son to die for his enemies. Furthermore it is seen more concretely in the behavior that Jesus has towards all those he encountered being compassionate and caring as is easily evident in the description of his behavior in the four gospels.  God’s love is also evident in his command that we are to love each other as we would wish that others would treat us. God command this because it is his nature to act that way.
Now I will try to address some of your individual questions that seem to have create doubts against this basic and clear description of God love.
First you mention God‘s hatred of Essau and that it seems as though he personally hates him.  I think most bible commentators would not interpret this statement as personal hatred but offer various other explanations.
Second, you mention ‘God is everything’ and this is not somethng that is accepted by Christian theology. God is not everything, he is infinitely more glorious and above everything. God is infinitely transcendent.  When the Bible says God created everythng ‘in Christ’ or ’through Christ‘, Christianity does not infer that everything is part of God. It just means the Son of God created everything and is the Father‘s word to do so.  Some see a difference between the pharse ’in Him‘ and ’though Him‘ and  then say that ’in Him‘ refers to the design of something, for example in the words ‘let there be light’ and that the actual creation of light by the words, indicates the ‘through them’. In other words, the Father both ‘designed’ everything ‘in’ the Son before actually creating everything ‘through’ him but in either case, this does not mean God is everything, it only means he created everything.
God in creating everything does in some way extend, or emmanate his glory in an additional way that would not have been if he did not create the universe but this does not mean that his essential glory can be increased, for that also was without limit before the creation. His own glory implies his own enjoyment of himself and all his esxcellencies so that his own delight in his own good will and glory, being the chief motive for all his works, somehow was exteneded by creating others that could also enjoy his goodness and glory, rather than only himself enjoying it throught eternity. So the exension of his glory through the creation is with repect to others enjoying him and not an actually increase of any property of God, being in every way without limit. His limitless and his glory includes the nature of his love for his creation full of brilliant and shining excellence alone worthy of worship and praise.
Third you raise the notion of what is perfect.  Perfect is God‘s excellence or glory, and might even be described at its centre his love and grace, which you are initially wondering about or how it exists. It implies all of God’s virtues and is principally revealed in the gospel of Christ where this love and grace was made known to us.  Again Christ in the graceful and caring way he lived is the best approximation of our imperfect understanding of what is perfect and this further back supports the answer of how God loves, especially when he willing suffered God‘s wrath on the cross for us.
Finally God has no imperfections so he is pure love without any admixture. This is what holy means - pure. This also means that he infinitely hates sin, or that which is not pure love and will punish the sinner. He will punish all those who are not loving and who refuse his love in Christ, for that is essentially rejectiong the greatest and purest expressiopn of love. Nothing is more hateful to oneself and to our neighbour than rejecting Christ held out to us in the gospel whereby we come to believe that he truly loves us.

Thank you so much! I am asking from the perspective and of somebody who is extremely interested in the nature of God and the Bible without actually believing in it but this is a wonderful answer. I don’t understand how he could be everything while being above it so I would love a more in depth explanation along with your perspective about perfection, but other than that you phrased your answer very well and I think you mostly resolved the questions I had! This is the most introspective response I’ve had to this question so far.

Very good answer. I do have two suggestions. I wouldn’t say Jesus is an approximation of God’s perfection b/c some may read that as a statement that Jesus isn’t perfect (or even God). Also you end with the “bad news” which is a perfect setup for the Good News of the Gospel, so some reordering of your answer might strengthen it. It ends with Law and wrath and justice, when it could end with forgiveness and mercy and grace and imputed righteousness—with love, and use the Law and wrath part to frame the Gospel. Just a suggestion.

@sofi I think a point that’s tripping you up is that God is not everything—he is holy, apart, separate from creation. He made and sustains everything, but he is not everything.

@sofi The verse in Colossians that you quoted isn’t saying God is everything, it’s showing how Jesus, the second person of the Trinity, created and sustains all creation. It’s establishing that Jesus is God—he’s part of the God-Head with the Father and Holy Spirit. If you search for the word “holy” (which means set apart or separate) in the Bible you will see that it is one of God’s key characteristics that is emphasized over and over again. God is holy separate from his creation.

@Mike it might be worth directly addressing OP’s misunderstanding of Colossians 1:16 in your answer in addition to your more general theological refutation of pantheism.

@sofi - Hi - if you really interested to explore the emaning of God perfection in a very introspective somewhat philosophical yet biblical way. I would refer you here:  http://edwards.yale.edu/archive?path=aHR0cDovL2Vkd2FyZHMueWFsZS5lZHUvY2dpLWJpbi9uZXdwaGlsby9nZXRvYmplY3QucGw/Yy43OjU6Mi53amVv

@bob - thanks for the comments . I did make a couple edits  i respone to improve a couple of the points.

Addressing what I think is the kernel of OP’s question…

If God were a perfect divine being, how would he feel? Or have any emotions at all? If God is a divine being, I can't understand how he would feel, including his love.

First I want to clear up a misunderstanding of Colossians 1:16.
God is not everything. God is holy (separate, apart)—this is shown all through the Scriptures from beginning to end. It is also shown from the very beginning in Genesis that while the creation was corrupted by sin, God is always without sin, holy, perfect, apart from sin and judging it. Even the seraphim (a kind of angelic being, I think) cannot look at God’s face-they must cover their faces with their wings:

1In the year that King Uzziah died I saw the Lord sitting upon a throne, high and lifted up; and the traina of his robe filled the temple. 2Above him stood the seraphim. Each had six wings: with two he covered his face, and with two he covered his feet, and with two he flew. 3And one called to another and said:
“Holy, holy, holy is the LORD of hosts;
the whole earth is full of his glory!”
4And the foundations of the thresholds shook at the voice of him who called, and the house was filled with smoke. 5And I said: “Woe is me! For I am lost; for I am a man of unclean lips, and I dwell in the midst of a people of unclean lips; for my eyes have seen the King, the LORD of hosts!”

(Isaiah 6:1-4, ESV)
Colossians 1:15-16 is not saying that God is everything. It is establishing Jesus as the God, the Second Person of the Trinity whose role in the creation was fearing everything and sustaining it all.
Back to the question “how can God have emotions?”.
Part of the answer is “we don’t know—it’s a mystery”. How does God have emotions? No idea. But he does. The same as us—how do we have emotions? No idea. But we do.
The other thing is that if you accept God as Creator, than framing emotions as human and projecting them back on God is backwards. Emotions, if possessed by God (and Scripture indicates they are), are not primarily human, but rather divine. God’s version of emotions are pure and perfect. Ours are imperfect, corrupted by our sin. God’s jealousy is holy. Ours not so much. God’s anger is righteous. Ours not. God’s hatred? Perfect. Ours? Wrong. And so on.
Also consider that love is not an emotion. Love is acting in the best interest of the other, putting their interests before your own. It generates emotions but is not an emotion. And God’s gift of his Son Jesus for our sins to pay our sin debt for us is the perfect picture of his love for us:

16“For God so loved the world, that he gave his only Son, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal life.

(John 3:16, ESV)

6For while we were still weak, at the right time Christ died for the ungodly. 7For one will scarcely die for a righteous person—though perhaps for a good person one would dare even to die— 8but God shows his love for us in that while we were still sinners, Christ died for us.

(Romans 5:6-8, ESV)
God’s love is not in conflict with his nature—it’s who he is, utterly holy (apart from his creation and from sin), righteous, just, judging sin, yet loving and merciful and kind too:

6The LORD passed before him and proclaimed, “The LORD, the LORD, a God merciful and gracious, slow to anger, and abounding in steadfast love and faithfulness, 7keeping steadfast love for thousands,a forgiving iniquity and transgression and sin, but who will by no means clear the guilty, visiting the iniquity of the fathers on the children and the children’s children, to the third and the fourth generation.

(Exodus 34:6-7, ESV)
The gospel is a reflection of who God is and his love for us!

"framing emotions as human and projecting them back on God is backwards" — Exactly. (+1 for this.) Humans are made in God's image, a reflection of what he is. But currently it is an imperfect image. People's emotions are exactly like God's emotions, but not always for the right reasons or expressed in the right way. The purpose of baptized converted Christians is to develop their characters to be perfect. E.g. 2 Corinthians 7:1: "Having therefore these promises, dearly beloved, let us cleanse ourselves from all filthiness of the flesh and spirit, perfecting holiness in the fear of God.".

Well, the original question seems to have many issues from a theological standpoint. God is a separate... something. Fundamentally all of creation is something that is "being" and God is not that.
The first issue I see is that your understanding of "omnipotent" is tinged by the modern "can literally do anything" concept. This is not our understanding of God. On the another question I addressed this concept. There are many things that God literally cannot do. (Our understanding based on what He has revealed to us)
God is not the embodiment of everything, but he does share in everything. This is called "Panentheism", but your statement is "Pantheism" (which has been considered Heresy, though not formally refuted probably because it is relatively obvious)

God is indeed the “wholly Other,” infinitely beyond created reality. Yet this same God shares fully in every aspect of that reality, filling it with His goodness, His light, His love, His Spirit. As a trinity or threefold unity of divine Persons, the Father, the Son and the Spirit dwell in an inexhaustible communion of mutual love. That love is so abundant that it overflows the limits of divine life, to embrace and transfigure the entire creation. Nothing lies outside the warmth of that embrace: not sin, not death, not even my friend’s well-intentioned agnosticism.  -Fr John Breck; OCA website


Now... about the question. How does God love?
According to the Christian faith “the greatest virtue is love” (1 Cor 13.13). Love is the “fulfilling of the law” of God (Rom 13.10). For God Himself is Love. (Orthodox Church of America)

Beloved, let us love one another; for love is of God, and he who loves is born of
God and knows God. He who does not love does not know God; for God is
love.
In this the love of God was made manifest among us, that God sent His
only Son into the world, so that we might live through Him.
In this is love, not that we loved God but that He loved us and sent
His Son to be the expiation for our sins.
Beloved, if God so loved us, we also ought to love one another. No man
has ever seen God; if we love one another, God abides in us and His
love is perfected in us.
By this we know that we abide in Him and He in us, because He has
given us of His own Spirit.
And we have seen and testify that the Father has sent His Son as the
Savior of the World. Whoever confesses that Jesus is the Son of God,
God abides in him, and he in God.
So we know and believe the love God has for us. God is love, and he
who abides in love abides in God, and God abides in him.
In this is love perfected with us, that we may have confidence for the
day of judgment, because as He is so are we in this world.
There is no fear in love, but perfect love casts out fear. For fear
has to do with punishment, and he who fears is not perfected in love.
We love, because He first loved us (1 John 4.7–19).


When the world became sinful and dead, “God so loved the world that He sent His only-begotten Son . . . not to condemn the world, but to save the world” (Jn 3.16, 12.47).


But God shows His love for us in that while we were yet sinners Christ died for us (Rom 5.8).


But when the goodness and love of God our Savior appeared, He saved us, not because of deeds done by us in righteousness, but in virtue of His own mercy, by the washing of regeneration and renewal in the Holy Spirit which He poured out upon us richly through Jesus Christ our Savior so that we might be made righteous by His grace and become heirs in hope of eternal life (Titus 3.4–7).


In the spiritual tradition of the Church, the aim of life as the “acquisition of the Holy Spirit” is expressed most perfectly in love (cf. Saint Macarius of Egypt, 4th c., Spiritual Homilies; Saint Seraphim of Sarov, 19th c., Conversation with N. Molovilov).


O Holy Love [i.e., the Holy Spirit of God], he who knows you not has never tasted the sweetness of your mercies which only living ­experience can give us. But he who has known you, or who has been known by you, can never have even the smallest doubt. For you are the fulfillment of the law, you who fills, burns, inflames, embraces my heart with a measureless love. You are the teacher of the prophets, the offspring of the apostles, the strength of the martyrs, the inspiration of the fathers and masters, the perfecting of all the saints. Only you, O Love, prepare even me for the true service of God (Saint Simeon the New Theologian, 11th c, Homily 53).

Could any of us (non-saints) truly say something more on the subject?

Your question holds in tension 3 ideas I want to focus on:

The proper meaning of God's perfection,

Imperfect humans He created, and the proper understanding of how God hates evil

Being humane and compassionate (with feelings) is part of perfect love.


First, some corrections on how you use the 6 verses you quoted:

Psalm 115:3 is not about omnipotence but of his complete freedom to act according to his love and faithfulness, in the context of protecting Israel against her enemies.  By extension, we can apply this Psalm to how God loves the body of Christ (the church).

Rom 9:13 should be interpreted in the context of God's gracious election of Israel.  Does it mean God "hate" other nations than Israel?  No, it's about preference, so it's correct to say that Israel is God's "chosen" nation to be the servant and model for other nations; it's a great burden to be "chosen" by God, exemplified in Jesus who is the embodiment of Israel.  So "hated Esau" in Rom 9:13 should be understood in the meaning that the Bible sometimes use "hate", which in this case does not mean an emotion that is opposite of "love" but of choosing Isaac, Jacob, etc. to realize His plan of salvation.  So it's wrong to quote this verse to support God's hatred of evil (although of course God hates evil).

1 John 4:16 and Col 1:16: Rather than saying "God is the embodiment of everything" (which smacks of pantheism), or "everything he has created is an extension of him" (which smacks of panentheism), the correct theology of creation implied by "all things have been created through him and for him" is that

God is the cause of everything that exists and that in the depth of our souls God imprints the capacity to love Him back (the purpose, the "for him" part).
God is present in all he created, perceptible to the degree according to the thing's nature.  Thus, as a human being we can rationally feel his "knowing" us and can freely respond to his "loving" us.  Or not.


Deut 32:4 can be read as Moses's final blessing to Israel (he was about to die).  Verses 3-4 is part of his introducing God to Israel as The Rock who is great, perfect, just, and faithful despite his chosen people's imperfection (v. 5).  It's not about God's perfection in His being (although we Christians believe that); v. 4 says "... his work is perfect; all his ways are just...", meaning, his dealing with Israel is perfect.

2 Tim 3:16 is about the inspiration and infallibility ("profitable") of Scriptures, though evangelicals also cite this verse to support the inerrancy of Scriptures.  So this is not about how God is free of human error (although He is, of course).


Now I can briefly address those 3 ideas in your question, partly by correcting false assumptions:

Perfect love contains 3 elements:

perfect reason-to-love (know what others need that is best for them),
perfect will-to-love (a want that leads to action resulting from knowing), and
perfect desire-to-love (along with the proper emotion resulting from the desiring as well as the enjoyment of the fruit of loving, "proper" = without psychological baggage like co-dependence).

Love without emotion would deficient; Christians are not Stoic.  Everything good that a human being is, desires, knows, wills, and does, God also is / has / wills / does it to perfection and we can see evidence of this in His incarnation, Jesus Christ.  So to say that "human-like" emotions detract from divine perfection would be wrong.  A perfect human like Jesus would love perfectly (with emotion).  Jesus was said to weep because he loved Lazarus (John 11:35) and knew the imminent destruction of Jerusalem (Luke 19:41-44) since he loved Jerusalem despite the corruption of its leaders.
I see why you want to say perfection is not the absence of imperfection, and I agree to some extent.  Because corruption (leading to perverted love or even evil) is a bigger problem than imperfection understood as lesser ability.  All Christians are apprentices to Jesus; we are all learning to become better, more perfect, lover.  As long as we repent of the corruption of love which we can see, imperfection is not the main issue but a challenge.  With regards to God, Christians believe that God hate corruption but have compassion toward humans who try to love imperfectly to whom He will give the grace and power to do better.

Perfect God can love imperfect (or even corrupt) humans without compromising His perfection because although humans possess something of God in our souls and how we mess up our potential for goodness by doing evil, our own evil desire, will, word, and deed are our own.  Because we are contingent created beings,

God who is full in himself doesn't need us for His perfection
God can hate the corruptions without hating us nor Himself, especially toward humble humans who realize that they need God to become more perfect lover


Yes, God loves all His creation, although because of free will we can reject his advances.  Even when his love is unrequited, he still has compassion for us and his waiting love should invite us to take the path of the prodigal son in anticipation of God's celebrating our future return (cf the parable of the lost sheep).  In compassion (because the evil in us causes US to become unhappy), he is being humane even towards those who reject him.  Again, being humane, hopeful and pursuing of the lost should not compromise his own perfection, but is a sign of his perfect love for us.


